# Fetch time like 1 day ago , 2 days after in Sequelize query in attributes

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, nest

I am using the Postgres database, my table is `category` where I stored `startdate`, Now when I fetch records then from currentdate to `startdate` how much difference I need in query?

I need something like 2 days ago , 2 days after ,1 hours ago in fetched records.

I am using sequelize , so anybody help me how to write query?

Thanks

Comment: your question was a little difficult to understand. assuming that you have your query ready, you just want to convert time in words relative to current time. in that case, you have to write logic for that. i mean there is no inbuild function which could help.

Comment: you can create a function in nodejs or a procedure in db. maybe it is possible to do it in query but the query will become a cluttered string.

Comment: @AmitKumar I am able to fetch all columns of category, but with that I also need like this category 2 days ago,this category 2 days after something like, so can you please help me how to write that query?

Answer (score 1):

```
const milliSecondInDay = 8.64e+7;
function getTimeDiffInWords(refDate) {
    const timeDiff_milli = refDate.valueOf() - Date.now();
    if (Math.abs(timeDiff_milli) > milliSecondInDay) {
        return `${Math.floor(Math.abs(timeDiff_milli / milliSecondInDay))} days ago`;
    }
    else if (Math.abs(timeDiff_milli) < milliSecondInDay) {
        return `${Math.floor(Math.abs(timeDiff_milli / milliSecondInDay))} days after`;
    }
   // rest of the conditions for after/before x hours
    return null;
}
```

This is a sample of what you need to do. I did in it javascript because i am not proficient with sql procedure but as long as you understand the concept, syntax can be searched online.

Comment: okay thanks @Amit kumar.
I will try and update here